# How to color highlight search results from XSLT?

Tags: xml, search, xslt, highlight

I have a simple one word widcard param called 'search' in XSLT 1.0.
I use the contains function to return the results .
How do I highlight this wildcard within the search results?

Here is my xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<xsl:param name="search"></xsl:param> 

<xsl:key name="uniquePublicationsGroupHeading" match="organisationUnitDetails/person/publications/publicationsgroup" use="publicationsgroupheading" />

<xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:call-template name="publicationsYearIndex"></xsl:call-template>
  <xsl:for-each select="//publicationsgroup[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('uniquePublicationsGroupHeading',publicationsgroupheading))]"> 
        <xsl:sort select="publicationsgroupheading" data-type="number" order="descending"/>

            <h4>Publications - <xsl:value-of select="publicationsgroupheading"/></h4>                
            <ol>                   
                <xsl:for-each select="key('uniquePublicationsGroupHeading',publicationsgroupheading)">   
                    <xsl:for-each select="publicationslist/publicationdetails">

                        <xsl:if test="contains(translate(current(),$uppercase,$lowercase),translate($search,$uppercase,$lowercase))">                              

                      <!--  TODO: NEED TO HIGHLIGHT wildcard param '$search' within current()....-->
                            <li class="margin-bottom"><xsl:value-of select="current()" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></li>

                        </xsl:if>

                    </xsl:for-each>  
                </xsl:for-each>                        
            </ol>               

    </xsl:for-each>       
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: XSLT is merely the program that transforms your input XML to HTML.  Hilighting would be handled by changing the HTML you output so this has little to do with XSLT per se.  If you were hand-coding the HTML what would you do?  Apply that to the HTML you are generating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jim noted, writing HTML to highlight search term is totally up to you.

Assuming you want to put all search term occurrences into `strong` tags, you'll need to process `current()` to add this markup to every appearance of search term. To do it you can replace

```
<xsl:value-of select="current()" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

with recursive template call:

```
<xsl:call-template name="highlight">
  <xsl:with-param name="string" select="current()"/>
  <xsl:with-param name="term" select="$search"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

and template which does replacing might look like

```
<xsl:template name="highlight">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:param name="term"/>

    <xsl:variable name="before" select="substring-before($string, $term)"/>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="starts-with($string, $term) or string-length($before) &gt; 0">
            <xsl:value-of select="$before"/>
            <!-- write whatever markup to highlight search term occurrence here -->
            <strong><xsl:value-of select="$term"/></strong>
            <xsl:variable name="after" select="substring-after($string, $term)"/>
            <xsl:if test="string-length($after) &gt; 0">
                <xsl:call-template name="highlight">
                    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$after"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="term" select="$term"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```